# Generate axlsx spreadsheets which are not easily formed by simple use of `add_row`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, axlsx

#### Background:

I have previously been using the gem [`spreadsheet`](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) to generate `.xls` spreadsheets as part of a ruby project.

However, this has caused various formatting and compatibility issues - the most recent being that old versions of excel [only support up to 256 columns per sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272729) (column `IV`). So, rather than hack around with VB or reformatting the data into multiple sheets, it makes more sense to refactor the code to use a `.xlsx` generator instead.

Enter [`axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx).

#### Problem:

My generated spreadsheets look something like this:

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
-----------------------------
aaa     | bbb     | ccc
-----------------------------
        | ddd     | eee
-----------------------------
        | fff     |
```

(There are actually more like 300 columns and 500 rows, but you get the idea.)

My old approach to generate this, using the `spreadsheet` gem, goes along the lines of:

```
def initialize
  @book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  @sheet = book.create_worksheet
  @columns = 0
end

def write_column(header, rows)
  @sheet[0, @columns] = header
  rows.each_with_index do |data, i|
    @sheet[i+1, @columns] = data
  end
  @columns += 1
end
```

**However**, this approach is invalid for `axlsx`. As [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Cell) states:

> **Note:** The recommended way to generate cells is via Worksheet#add_row

### Question:

What is the "right" way to generate spreadsheets such as the above, which clearly "look like" they should be generated by an `add_column` method rather than `add_row`?

The documented approach is to do something like:

```
sheet.add_row ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
sheet.add_row ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
sheet.add_row [nil, 'ddd', 'eee']
sheet.add_row [nil, 'fff', nil]
```

...However, this is not great since I'm now unable to directly loop through each column of data.

Another approach could be to initialise a big grid of cells, like:

```
sheet.add_row ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
3.times { sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil] }
```

And then add my data in a separate step, like:

```
sheet["A2"] = "aaa"
```

However, this feels *wrong* - as it's abusing the way in which sheets get generated.

How would the community advise sheets like this be generated?

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving columns of data, have you tried placing each column as a row in an intermediate array, transposing it, and loading its rows into the Axlsx spreadsheet?

```
intermediate = [column1, column2, column3]
sheet.add_row ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3']
intermediate.transpose.each do |row|
  sheet.add_row row
end
```

I don't know what the "proper" way would be, but transpose is very useful for these kinds of problems.

That may be memory intensive with large amounts of data btw.

Comment: Incidentally, transpose will require normalized rows, each with the same number of elements.

Comment: Yes, this is roughly what I've gone with for now in lieu of a "better" recommendation. I'll post my own code on Monday (it's 5:30 on Friday and I want to go home!), but this is roughly the approach I took.